# Can not install Sitecore.CLI for Sitecore 10

Tags: sitecore-cli, scs

I am following the guide specified [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/install-sitecore-command-line-interface.html). I can successfully run the command `dotnet new tool-manifest` however I get an error when I run

```
dotnet tool install Sitecore.CLI --add-source https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'sitecore.cli' from remote source 'https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/FindPackagesById()?id='sitecore.cli'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [***]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   The content at 'https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/FindPackagesById()?id='sitecore.cli'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' is not valid XML. [**]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.405\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method. [***]
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'sitecore.cli' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json from your machine? Can the PowerShell window access that? Try pinging sitecore.myget.org and check.

Comment: I can reach that url from my machine. It loads a json response.

Answer (score 2):

I found the fix to this. In Visual Studio 2017 or 2019:

Navigate to `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources` and remove the reference to Sitecore NuGet. This was there from a previous setup of Sitecore. My theory is that it conflicted with this installation.

Packages Sources after removing the Sitecore Source:

[image]