# Sitecore CLI Error: It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs

Tags: sitecore-cli

I am new to Sitecore and trying to sync Sitecore content using `Sitecore CLI`. I am using `Sitecore 10.2` version and `CLI 4.2.1` version. I have installed `Microsoft .NET Core SDK`, `ASP.NET Core Runtime`

[image]

while I am trying to run `dotnet new tool-manifest`, it is giving below error:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a `.NET Core` SDK from:
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/can-not-install-sitecore-cli-for-sitecore-10

Comment: Follow this blog as well - https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/2021/03/09/quick-start-to-the-sitecore-cli/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166337/it-was-not-possible-to-find-any-installed-net-core-sdks-error

Answer (score 1):

Check if You forgot to create the dotnet tool manifest file via,

```
powershell dotnet new tool-manifest
```

Follow this blog for more details - https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/2021/03/09/quick-start-to-the-sitecore-cli/

If this doesn't solve your issue then check below as per [Can not install Sitecore.CLI for Sitecore 10](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/can-not-install-sitecore-cli-for-sitecore-10-)

In Visual Studio 2017 or 2019:

Navigate to `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources` and remove the reference to Sitecore NuGet. This was there from a previous setup of Sitecore. My theory is that it conflicted with this installation.

Packages Sources after removing the Sitecore Source:

[image]